# Convert MYSQL query into Laravel 5 query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Okay so i have got my project working however a lot of my database are kind of raw queries and i want to do it in the laravel 5 way.

So far I have managed to do some simple ones in laravel 5 easily however I am struggling to replicate this query in laravel:

```
$ave=DB::select("SELECT `question`.`questionID`,
COUNT(`reviewmeta`.`id`) as count,  `reviewmeta`.`answer` 
FROM `question` 
JOIN `reviewmeta` 
ON (`question`.`questionID` = `reviewmeta`.`questionID`) 
WHERE `question`.`watchID`='".$hwid."' 
AND  `question`.`type`='FFT' 
GROUP BY `reviewmeta`.`answer` ");
```

For an example this is how I converted one of my raw queries:

**Laravel 5 way**

```
public static function getWatchListInfo($serviceIDS){
    $services = DB::table('services')
                ->distinct()
                ->leftJoin('reviews','services.serviceID','=','reviews.serviceID')
                ->join('service_categories','services.type','=','service_categories.categoryID')
                ->select('services.id','services.name','services.review_count_approved','reviews.escalate','services.average_rating','service_categories.name as catName')
                ->whereIn('services.serviceID',$serviceIDS);
    return $services;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: implementing count into the select

Comment: Make that part of the question as it is - in it's current form - is not in an answerable format.

Comment: sorry i was basically asking if someone could show me how to convert that sql query into laravels eloquent way

Comment: It's quite alright, just keep in mind next time that we like to see own effort and questions that can be answered (The format "How to do X?" might be OK, depending on the situation)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add ->count() like this :

->whereIn('services.serviceID',$serviceIDS)->count()

Comment: Sorry that Laravel 5 example it working correctly. i need the first raw sql query converted to this eloquent approach but im unsure with the count part

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('questions')
->select(['reviewmeta.answer', DB::raw('COUNT(reviewmeta.id) as count')])
->leftJoin('reviewmeta', 'question.questionID', '=' ,'eviewmeta.questionID')
->where('question.watchID', $hwid)
->where('question.type', 'FFT')
->groupBy('reviewmeta.answer');
```

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, it's been some time since I've done laravel related queries.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same with @Andrew's answer, just you can use select function like this.

```
$ave=DB::table('questions')
->select('question.questionID', DB::raw('COUNT(reviewmeta.id) as count'),'reviewmeta.answer')
->join('reviewmeta', 'question.questionID', '=' ,'reviewmeta.questionID')
->where('question.watchID', $hwid)
->where('question.type', 'FFT')
->groupBy('reviewmeta.answer');
```